# Is it possible to use IBM Websphere traditional thinclient SOAP code with Websphere liberty?

Tags: java, websphere, websphere-liberty

We have code that was based with IBM Websphere traditional, we are trying to use Websphere Liberty.  In trying to use this code below, we are getting class not found errors.

We originally used the thinclient jar file

This is an error we are getting:

```
[ERROR   ] SRVE0777E: Exception thrown by application class 'com.ibm.ws.webservices.multiprotocol.discovery.ServiceProviderManager.<clinit>:139'
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
```

And using code:

```
com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.utils.QNameTable.createQName
```

Here are the **features** in **Websphere liberty**:

> WebSphere Application Server 21.0.0.3/wlp-1.0.50.cl210320210309-1101
>
> webProfile-8.0
>
> localConnector-1.0
>
> json-1.0
>
> jaxws-2.2

In RAD, this code was generated with that web services code generation tool.   Trying to see if this code will run in Liberty.  Also we added thinclient.jar in our classpath from RAD/Websphere

Click `wsdl file ->click on Web Services -> click on Generate Client`.

And some of the packages and code used:

```
public class PFSServiceLocator extends com.ibm.ws.webservices.multiprotocol.AgnosticService implements com.ibm.ws.webservices.multiprotocol.GeneratedService {


    public PFSServiceLocator() {
        super(com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.utils.QNameTable.createQName(
           "http://table.com/Utilities",
           "PFSService"));

        context.setLocatorName("core.ws.PFSServiceLocator");
    }


    public ws.IPFSService getBasicHttpEndpoint(java.net.URL portAddress) throws javax.xml.rpc.ServiceException {
        ws.IPFSService _stub =
            (ws.IPFSService) getStub(
                basicHttpEndpointPortName,
                (String) getPort2NamespaceMap().get(basicHttpEndpointPortName),
                .IPFSService.class,
                "ws.BasicHttpEndpointStub",
                portAddress.toString());
        if (_stub instanceof com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.client.Stub) {
            ((com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.client.Stub) _stub).setPortName(basicHttpEndpointWSDDPortName);
        }
        return _stub;
    }
```

Comment: What Liberty features do you have installed? And are you referencing those classes above directly, or are they being attempted due to some other API references, like JAX-WS or something?

Comment: We installed the jax-ws but still the same issue.  Class not found.  So we were using RAD and they created the IBM references that way.  Now we want to use liberty, we thought would be the same modules..

Comment: Please include the exact Liberty Features you have installed, including their versions. And then please show a piece of code that makes the Web Service call so we can see like if it's using javax classes or com.ibm classes directly.

Comment: I updated, see new edits

Comment: This looks along the lines what I looking for.

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was-liberty/core?topic=liberty-deploying-jax-ws-applications

Comment: Does that reference give you steps that work for you? I admit I don't know if using RAD to generate a client from WSDL automatically produces code that works in both tWAS and Liberty, or whether you have to choose one or the other, for instance. I'd think that if it lets you select the JAX-WS version, that _should_ work with the correct Liberty features installed. But I'm only guessing there.

Comment: No it didn't work per the error.  It looks like the link was all jax-ws implementation, no iBM references.  May have to convert to remove all the IBM references.  Seems odd, I thought that there might be a migration for it.  I see your an IBM person, let me know if you find anything.  Would be useful.  We have a lot of this type of code

Comment: What do you think @dbreaux

Any suggestions. I would assume IBM has a way to migrate legacy SOAP web service clients

Comment: Do you know if the SOAP Client you are trying to migrate to Liberty is JAX-RPC or JAX-WS? I'm not familiar with deploying a SOAP Web Services app with RAD, so I'm not sure if it's generating that ServiceLocator class or that is already in your application, but if RAD is generating it for you,  then it is generating JAX-RPC client artifacts. These aren't deploying to Liberty because Liberty doesn't support JAX-RPC. A simple way to check, would be to look at your business logic for any JAX-RPC imports (`javax.xml.rpc` packages).

Comment: Yea, these are jax RPC I believe.  I wish there was a migration tool.  We have a lot of code that I guess has to run in websphere